Swapping Elements and Negating One
How can the list={5, 2} be transformed into {2, -5} or { -2, 5 }, with the rule being to swap the positions of the two elements in the list and take the opposite of one of them?
My method is:
list = {5, 2}
{list[[2]], -list[[1]]}
{-list[[2]], list[[1]]}

OR
list = {5, 2}
{#2, -#1} & @@ # &@list
{-#2, #1} & @@ # &@list

Are there alternative methods to implement this transformation?

{#2, -#1} & @@ # &@list  may be written as {#2, -#1} & @@ list (or {#2, -#1} &[Sequence @@ list], or {#2, -#1} &[Delete[list, 0]], among other ways)

The one-argument Cross does that:
list = {5, 2};
Cross[list]
(* {-2, 5} *)


One way (assuming I have intepreted your question correctly):
Replace[list, {x_, y_} :> {y, -x}]

(* {2, -5} *)


Replace[list, {x_, y_} :> {{y, -x}, {-y, x}}]

(* {{2, -5}, {-2, 5}} *)


list = {5, 2};

Reverse@list {1, -1}
Reverse@list {-1, 1}


{2, -5}


{-2, 5}

For this two element list, RotateRight or RotateLeft can also be used.

For a list with more items, e.g., if the first two items need to undergo such a transformation, a pattern can be used.
list /. {x_, y_, z___} :> {y, -x, z}


{2, -5}

{1, 2, 3, 4} /. {x_, y_, z___} :> {y, -x, z}


{2, -1, 3, 4}


Use ReplacePart and MapIndexed
Clear["Global`*"];
list = {5, 2};
reversedList = Reverse@list;

baseElement=reversedList;
result = 
  MapIndexed[
    ReplacePart[baseElement,
      {
       originalIndex = #2[[1]]; originalEle = #1; 
       originalIndex -> -originalEle
      }
    ] &,
    reversedList
  ]


RotationTransform:
RotationTransform[π/2]@{5, 2}
(* {-2, 5} *)

RotationTransform[-π/2]@{5, 2}
(* {2, -5} *)

RotationMatrix:
RotationMatrix[Pi/2] . {5, 2}
(* {-2, 5} *)

RotationMatrix[-Pi/2] . {5, 2}
(* {2, -5} *)

I don't see your effort in understanding the code you've copied (-1):
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/307268/1871
How to find the function expression for the area of the liquid surface as a right triangular prism tilts about the axis AC?

tran = Apply@Function[{x, y}, {{y, -x},{-y, x}}];
tran@{5,2}


{{2, -5}, {-2, 5}}


m1 = {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}; m2 = {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}; {m1 . {5, 2}, m2 . {5, 2}}
